# open source CRFs implementation for computer vision problems?

Tags: c++, opencv, open-source, machine-learning, computer-vision

There are several open source implementations of conditional random fields (CRFs) in C++, such as CRF++, FlexCRF, etc. But from the manual, I can only understand how to use them for 1-D problems such as text tagging, it's not clear how to apply them in 2-D vision problems, suppose I have computed the association potentials at each node and the interaction potentials at each edge.

Did anyone use these packages for vision problems, e.g., segmentation? Or they simply cannot be used in this way?

All in all, is there any open source packages of CRFs for vision problems?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happened upon this question by accident and just wanted to say I made a python implementation of structured support vector machines for CRF learning that is suitable for vision applications: https://github.com/amueller/pystruct

Answer (score 6):

The newest version of dlib has support for learning pairwise Markov random field models over arbitrary graph structures (including 2-D grids).  It estimates the parameters in a max-margin sense (i.e. using a structural SVM) rather than in a maximum likelihood sense (i.e. CRF), but if all you want to do is predict a graph labeling then either method is just as good.

There is an [example program](http://dlib.net/graph_labeling_ex.cpp.html) that shows how to use this stuff on a simple example graph.  The example puts feature vectors at each node and the structured SVM uses them to learn how to correctly label the nodes in the graph.  Note that you can change the dimensionality of the feature vectors by modifying the typedefs at the top of the file.  Also, if you already have a complete model and just want to find the most probable labeling then you can call the underlying [min-cut based inference routine](http://dlib.net/optimization.html#find_max_factor_graph_potts) directly.

In general, I would say that the best way to approach these problems is to define the graphical model you want to use and then select a parameter learning method that works with it.  So in this case I imagine you are interested in some kind of pairwise Markov random field model.  In particular, the kind of model where the most probable assignment can be found with a min-cut/max-flow algorithm.  Then in this case, it turns out that a structural SVM is a natural way to find the parameters of the model since a structural SVM only requires the ability to find maximum probability assignments.  Finding the parameters via maximum likelihood (i.e. treating this as a CRF) would require you to additionally have some way to compute sums over the graph variables, but this is pretty hard with these kinds of models.  For this kind of model, all the CRF methods I know about are approximations, while the SVM method in dlib uses an exact solver.  By that I mean, one of the parameters of the algorithm is an epsilon value that says "run until you find the optimal parameters to within epsilon accuracy", and the algorithm can do this efficiently every time.

There was a good [tutorial](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/cvpr2012tutorial/) on this topic at this year's computer vision and pattern recognition conference.  There is also a good book on [Structured Prediction and Learning in Computer Vision](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/papers/nowozin2011structured-tutorial.pdf) written by the presenters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Davis! I'm not a machine learning guy so a couple questions: 1). What is the term/name for the method with structural SVM based learning on graph models, maybe some papers or tutorials on it? 2). What I'm trying to do is to segment table structures out of documents, do you think structural SVM will be more appropriate? If you haven't implemented CRFs, you might consider doing so because it's interesting to make comparisons on different models:D. A more concrete questions is as below.

Comment: 3) My work requires learning, otherwise the max-flow/min-cut algorithm will suffice. And I Just took a quick look at your pointer: it seems that the data entry in each node is essentially 1-D, i.e. data[0] = 1 means false and data[1] = 1 means true. Is it possible to pass a feature vector to each node so that I don't have to decide the data value myself? Ideally, I'd like to pass Association potentials to each node and Interaction potentials (both float-value feature vectors) to each edge. Could you please illustrate a bit on this regard? I appreciate your time!

Comment: I updated my answer to try and answer your questions.  I'm also the author of dlib, so you can email me or post on the dlib forums if you have more dlib specific questions :)